# Dynamic columns adding HTML

Tags: html, css

**I have a table that can always have columns added and removed from it:**

```css
#tablecon{
    overflow: scroll;
    width:95%; 
    display: flexbox;
    align-items: stretch;
}

table  {
    border:solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color :rgb(202, 202, 202);
    width:100%; 
    font-size: medium;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

th,td {
    font-size: 23px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    border-top:solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color :rgb(202, 202, 202);
}
```

```html
<div id = "tablecon">
  <table>
    <thead id ="heads">
      <th>
        <p>Issue Key</p>
        <div class= "controls">
          <img  class = "sort_controls" id = "sort_a_ik" src="/download/resources/com.snse.searchsn/images/up.png" alt="">
          <img class = "sort_controls"  id = "sort_d_ik"src="/download/resources/com.snse.searchsn/images/down.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <p>Component</p>
        <div class= "controls">
          <img  class = "sort_controls" id = "sort_a_comp" src="/download/resources/com.snse.searchsn/images/up.png" alt="">
          <img class = "sort_controls"  id = "sort_d_comp"src="/download/resources/com.snse.searchsn/images/down.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <p>S/N</p>
        <div class = "nonetext">
          <input type="text" id = "SNser" class= "search_input" placeholder="Search">
          <div class= "controls">
            <img  class = "sort_controls" id = "sort_a_SN" src="/download/resources/com.snse.searchsn/images/up.png" alt="">
            <img class = "sort_controls"  id = "sort_d_SN"src="/download/resources/com.snse.searchsn/images/down.png" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <p>P/N</p>
        <div class = "nonetext">
          <input type="text" id = "PNser" class= "search_input" placeholder="Search">
          <div class= "controls">
            <img  class = "sort_controls" id = "sort_a_PN" src="/download/resources/com.snse.searchsn/images/up.png" alt="">
            <img class = "sort_controls"  id = "sort_d_PN"src="/download/resources/com.snse.searchsn/images/down.png" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <p>Compatibility</p>
        <div class= "controls">
          <img  class = "sort_controls" id = "sort_a_ver" src="/download/resources/com.snse.searchsn/images/up.png" alt="">
          <img class = "sort_controls"  id = "sort_d_ver"src="/download/resources/com.snse.searchsn/images/down.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id ="populate_me">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

On some of the `headers` there is also an input to search for the corresponding column and two clickable images to sort ascending or descending by that column.

I want the table to have as much space as it needs to display correctly, so I have set the containers overflow to scroll. Still the table gets messed up as I add new columns though.

**How can I make the table not to be affected by added columns (meaning all the existing columns stay the same width ?**

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the `width:100%` in the `table`, and replace it with `min-width:100%`, your table will always be taking the full screen and even more. Then you can add in your `td, th` the same property `min-width:200px`. You can change the value 200 by something else.

Here is the result:

```css
#tablecon{
  overflow: scroll;
  width:95%; 
  display: flexbox;
  align-items: stretch;
}

table  {
  border:solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color :rgb(202, 202, 202);
  font-size: medium;
  table-layout:fixed;
  min-width:100%;
}
th,td {
  font-size: 23px;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  border-top:solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color :rgb(202, 202, 202);
}
td, th{
  min-width:200px;
}
```

Comment: did just that and the columns are still getting messed up , any other suggestions? am I missing something?

Comment: @YotamAbt, changed my answer, don't know if it's the result you are waiting for.